# Vagrant : Connect from client to local https site

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am working on a chef project which is running in Vagrant. I have installed chef server on my local machine and I need to connect it from vagrant instance. I am getting a connection refused. I have added port-forwarding, but vagrant wont let me forward port-443 as it's already occupied. My chef server is running on https i.e port-443.

Error log :

```
[2019-05-03T10:21:00+00:00] INFO: Client key /etc/chef/client.pem is not present - registering
[2019-05-03T10:21:00+00:00] ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://my-system-product-name/organizations/internetdevelopment/clients, retry 1/5
[2019-05-03T10:21:05+00:00] ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://my-system-product-name/organizations/internetdevelopment/clients, retry 2/5
```

VagrantFile :

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 8443
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

Answer (score 1):

i would offer you to assign a [static ip address](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html#static-ip) to your vagrant virtual machine (vm) rather than use a port forwarding.

> You can also specify a static IP address for the machine. This lets you access the Vagrant managed machine using a static, known IP. The Vagrantfile for a static IP looks like this:
>
> `Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
>     config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
>   end`
>
> It is up to the users to make sure that the static IP does not collide with any other machines on the same network.
>
> While you can choose any IP you would like, you should use an IP from the reserved private address space. These IPs are guaranteed to never be publicly routable, and most routers actually block traffic from going to them from the outside world.